# Calling HTTP Webservice with Jquery and getting XML back

Tags: jquery, asmx

I have a web service that I am trying to call with jQuery.  It is supposed to return a bunch of XML data, but I can not seem to get it to work.

This is the ws with the params:

> http://campaign.vialunatechnology.com/service/CampaignService.asmx/GetTargetDetails?urlName=richsangillo&campaignGuid=5475D3AB-313D-47C0-842D-D916B43658D1

Here is the jQuery code I am using.

```
var UrlName = "richsangillo";
var GUID = "5475D3AB-313D-47C0-842D-D916B43658D1";
var TID = "7006806";
var PageID = "53619";
var SID = "cd4p4y55q1i4vayzdw1fxsa0";

var arr= new Array();
var loopCounter = 0;



$.ajax({type: "GET",url:"http://campaign.vialunatechnology.com/service/CampaignService.asmx/GetTargetDetails?urlName=" + UrlName + "&campaignGuid=" + GUID,dataType: "xml",success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('xmlNode').each(
                function() 
                {
                    arr[loopCounter] = $(this).find('xmlNode').text();
                    loopCounter += 1;
                });
            }});
```

Comment: What is the domain you are making this request from?

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in JSFiddle, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://campaign.vialunatechnology.com/service/CampaignService.asmx/GetTargetDetails?urlName=richsangillo&campaignGuid=5475D3AB-313D-47C0-842D-D916B43658D1.
>   Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If you want to enable cross origin requests, follow the instructions on this page:

http://enable-cors.org/